# Correct use of anchor in rails to link_to different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, anchor

I am trying to use correctly :anchor in my Rails app but I can't get it work correctly.

my example:

```
<% = link_to('Artist Page', artists_path(artist, :anchor => 'ranking')) %>
```

and the link I get:

/artists.1-young-the-giant#ranking

instead of:

/artists/1-young-the-giant#ranking

So I am getting a "dot" instead or a "forward slash".

I have search a lot inside stackoverflow and I see similar examples with same result.

Any idea?

I am using the last version of Rails. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<% = link_to('Artist Page', artist_path(artist, :anchor => 'ranking')) %>
```

`artist_path` should be singular as you're not querying the index action.

Check out this part of Rails guides for more info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

These are the paths generated for you when you use the resource keyword in your routes:

```
artists_path returns /artists
new_artist_path returns /artists/new
edit_artist_path(:id) returns /artists/:id/edit
artist_path(:id) returns /artists/:id
```

Comment: Great! Now is working. Ok, I thought was requiered the list where are all the artists that is "artists_path" instead of the singular page "artist_path". Now is working perfectly! Thanks for the fast help. What about if I want to put inside this variable: <% = link_to ("#{@connections['friends_count'].to_s} #{t('boxcommon.friends.other')}", artist_path(artist, :anchor => 'friends')) %>

Comment: No worries, have fun ;)

Comment: Ok, i get it. = link_to "#{@connections['friends_count'].to_s} #{t('boxcommon.friends.other')}", artist_path(artist, :anchor => 'friends') Thank you

Comment: You might wanna consider using I18n pluralization or interpolation for your #{@connections['friends_count'].to_s} #{t('boxcommon.friends.other')}, check out how it works here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation